# Can't set header after they are sent error when using .on('error') in router.post()

Tags: node.js, express

I was using express and [ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp) packages to make an app that receives post requests and connects to my ftp server. When wrong user or password are entered, I tried to use `c.on('error', callback)` to catch the error and redirect to the signin page.

signin.js

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var checkNotLogin = require('../middlewares/check').checkNotLogin;
var c = new require('ftp')();

router.get('/', checkNotLogin, function(req, res, next){
    res.render('signin');
});

router.post('/', checkNotLogin, function(req, res, next){
    var name = req.body.usrname;
    var password = req.body.password; 
    var option = {
        port: 21,
        host: 'localhost',
        user: name,
        pass: password
    };

    c.on('ready', function(){
        req.session.user = name;
        req.session.pass = password
        console.log('You are connected');
        return res.redirect('/ftp/'+name); 
    });

    c.on('error', function(err){
        console.log(err.message);
        return res.redirect('signin');
    });

    c.connect(option);
});

module.exports = router;
```

The problem is that when the wrong user or password being entered at the first time, the redirection to the signin(itself) page works. However, when I try it again, the app crashed and it reported "cant set headers after they are sent".

Thank you in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from the scope of your ftp client. Currently it is shared by all requests. So every time you call `c.on(...)`, you add a new event listener to the same client. So when an event is triggered, all listeners are notified, resulting in multiple response being sent.

You need to scope the ftp client to your request:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var checkNotLogin = require('../middlewares/check').checkNotLogin;
var ftp = require('ftp');

router.get('/', checkNotLogin, function(req, res, next){
    res.render('signin');
});

router.post('/', checkNotLogin, function(req, res, next){
    var c = new ftp();
    var name = req.body.usrname;
    var password = req.body.password; 
    var option = {
        port: 21,
        host: 'localhost',
        user: name,
        pass: password
    };

    c.on('ready', function(){
        req.session.user = name;
        req.session.pass = password
        console.log('You are connected');
        return res.redirect('/ftp/'+name); 
    });

    c.on('error', function(err){
        console.log(err.message);
        return res.redirect('signin');
    });

    c.connect(option);
});

module.exports = router;
```